# Getting the percentages after perfoming groupby in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

After performing the next groupby()

```
data.groupby(["Gender",'Gain/Loss',"Final corrected classification"]).size()
Gender  Gain/Loss  Final corrected classification
Female  Gain       Benign                             5619
                   Likely Benign                      7288
                   Likely Pathogenic                   324
                   Pathogenic                          177
                   VUS                                 215
        Loss       Benign                             1539
                   Likely Benign                      2268
                   Likely Pathogenic                   382
                   Pathogenic                          318
                   VUS                                 148
Male    Gain       Benign                             9832
                   Likely Benign                     11617
                   Likely Pathogenic                   396
                   Pathogenic                          267
                   VUS                                 290
        Loss       Benign                             2934
                   Likely Benign                      3442
                   Likely Pathogenic                   574
                   Pathogenic                          330
                   VUS                                 235
dtype: int64
```

I would like to add the percentages of each value in a new columns next to the final corrected classification as I have done manually in the next example.

```
Gender  Gain/Loss  Final corrected classification           %
Female  Gain       Benign                             5619 11.6569
...
dtype: int64
```

Any idea of how I can do this.

Comment: Provide the original dataframe as well

Comment: How is count `15.0121` ?

Comment: @jezrael: I had the same question. Not getting this value in any way :/

Comment: moys, I cant provide the data frame for patient confidentiality

Comment: % is corrected now. This is the % of cases considering the total of cases what is 48203

Comment: How you got `11.6569`? show some calculation

Comment: you can do it this way `df['percentage'] = (df['Count']/df['Count'].sum())*100`

Comment: @moys - yop, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not 100% clear, what percentage is used, so I use percentage of first level `Gender` here by pass `level=[0]` to `sum` and divide original `Series`, last pass to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

*Notice: You can pass another level or levels to sum like `s.sum(level=[1])` or `s.sum(level=[0,1])`*

```
s = data.groupby(["Gender",'Gain/Loss',"Final corrected classification"]).size()

df = pd.concat([s, s.div(s.sum(level=[0])).mul(100)],
               keys=('val','%'),
               axis=1)
print (df)
                                                   val          %
Gender Gain/Loss Final corrected classification                  
Female Gain      Benign                           5619  30.741875
                 Likely Benign                    7288  39.873071
                 Likely Pathogenic                 324   1.772623
                 Pathogenic                        177   0.968377
                 VUS                               215   1.176277
       Loss      Benign                           1539   8.419958
                 Likely Benign                    2268  12.408360
                 Likely Pathogenic                 382   2.089944
                 Pathogenic                        318   1.739796
                 VUS                               148   0.809717
Male   Gain      Benign                           9832  32.864258
                 Likely Benign                   11617  38.830765
                 Likely Pathogenic                 396   1.323662
                 Pathogenic                        267   0.892469
                 VUS                               290   0.969349
       Loss      Benign                           2934   9.807133
                 Likely Benign                    3442  11.505164
                 Likely Pathogenic                 574   1.918642
                 Pathogenic                        330   1.103052
                 VUS                               235   0.785507
```

EDIT: If need percentage of all values:

```
df = pd.concat([s, s.div(s.sum()).mul(100)],
               keys=('val','%'),
               axis=1)
print (df)
                                                   val          %
Gender Gain/Loss Final corrected classification                  
Female Gain      Benign                           5619  11.658886
                 Likely Benign                    7288  15.121901
                 Likely Pathogenic                 324   0.672269
                 Pathogenic                        177   0.367258
                 VUS                               215   0.446104
       Loss      Benign                           1539   3.193277
                 Likely Benign                    2268   4.705882
                 Likely Pathogenic                 382   0.792613
                 Pathogenic                        318   0.659819
                 VUS                               148   0.307086
Male   Gain      Benign                           9832  20.400456
                 Likely Benign                   11617  24.104160
                 Likely Pathogenic                 396   0.821662
                 Pathogenic                        267   0.553999
                 VUS                               290   0.601722
       Loss      Benign                           2934   6.087768
                 Likely Benign                    3442   7.141820
                 Likely Pathogenic                 574   1.190995
                 Pathogenic                        330   0.684718
                 VUS                               235   0.487602
```